# how to enable browser caching in jsf

Tags: jsf, web-applications, jsf-2, browser-cache

I have created a web application using JSF 2.0. I got feedback from my friend saying I should do "Browser Caching" as I have many images.

However I don't know how to do same in JSF. Any idea/ hint would be appreciated.

Concept on what to be done would also work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `<h:graphicImage name="...">` instead of `<img src="...">`. This way the default JSF resource handler will instruct the browser to cache them for 1 week by default, which is configureable with an implementation dependent context parameter, which is the following in case of Mojarra:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.defaultResourceMaxAge</param-name>
    <param-value>3628800000</param-value> <!-- 6 weeks -->  
</context-param>
```

Note, the same applies when using `<h:outputScript>` and `<h:outputStylesheet>` instead of `<script>` and `<link rel="stylesheet">`.

Comment: Then your friend has no idea what he is talking about :) One week is only a little, some overzealous webapp performance test tools may indeed warn on that. Increase it to 2 weeks or so. Or just test and finetune it *yourself*, e.g. http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/

Comment: thanks, I will accept answer once SO time is over.. I hate this feature of SO... have to wait to accept answer...