# How to enable cache for a JSF application

Tags: jsf, caching, primefaces

I am using Primefaces with JSF application and some initial load time to load my first screen. I tried following things to see if it helps to enable cache

1. set my server to production
2. add `<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="max-age=2592000, public"/>` to my html page header

However all the css and js files from primefaces show as no-cache. How do i turn on caching for them?

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate 
Content-Type:text/css Date:Wed, 02 Sep 2015 06:53:44 GMT 
Expires:Wed, 14 Oct 2015 06:53:44 GMT 
Last-Modified:Wed, 02 Sep 2015 06:46:54 GMT 
Pragma:no-cache
```

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800460/how-to-remove-jsf-2-cache (answer also says "<meta http-equiv> tags are ignored")

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999323/how-to-enable-browser-caching-in-jsf